# Correlation table with p-values DVs on one axis IVs on the other by dataframe

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to r and I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem. I am creating correlation tables with a lot of independent variables and the same two groups of dependent variables. I use the costars function I got from this function from this site (http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/elegant-correlation-table-using-xtable-r-package#combine-matrix-of-correlation-coefficients-and-significance-levels). The output looks like this:

```
|        | allo      | csub      | glumet    |
|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| allo   |           |           |           |
| csub   |  0.57**** |           |           |
| glumet |  0.58**** |  0.17**** |           |
| lipmet |  0.41**** |  0.10**   |  0.36**** |
```

I would like to be able to take one dataframe I have that has my dependent variables have them along one (x) axis and have the changing list of independent variables along the other (y) axis. Which would look something like this:

```
|         | allo      | csub      | glumet    |
|---------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| A1SEMA  | -0.19**** | -0.17**** |  0.11***  |
| A1SEMD  |  0.05     |  0.00     | -0.02     |
| A1SMMOD | -0.12**** | -0.11***  |  0.04     |
```

This is the code I use after the code included from the website I linked to above.  (allo is one of the data frames containing my dependent variables)

```
corvar <- select(bio, M2ID, A1SEMA, A1SEMD, A1SMMOD, A1SEFA, A1SEFD, A1SEFMOD, A1SEMAPA)
corvar1 <- left_join(allo, corvar)
corvar1 <- select(corvar1, -1)
var1 <- corstars(corvar1)
```

I then go and export everything to excel (per the request of my advisor).

If I had to guess I would need to change the rcorr part of the costars function (line 7) but I have no idea what to change it to in order to get the desired output.

Here is the corstarts function

```
corstars <-function(x, method=c("pearson", "spearman"), 
removeTriangle=c("upper", "lower"),
                result=c("none", "html", "latex")){
#Compute correlation matrix
require(Hmisc)
x <- as.matrix(x)
correlation_matrix<-rcorr(x, type=method[1])
R <- correlation_matrix$r # Matrix of correlation coeficients
p <- correlation_matrix$P # Matrix of p-value 

## Define notions for significance levels; spacing is important.
mystars <- ifelse(p < .0001, "****", ifelse(p < .001, "*** ", ifelse(p < .01, "**  ", ifelse(p < .05, "*   ", "    "))))

## trunctuate the correlation matrix to two decimal
R <- format(round(cbind(rep(-1.11, ncol(x)), R), 2))[,-1]

## build a new matrix that includes the correlations with their apropriate stars
Rnew <- matrix(paste(R, mystars, sep=""), ncol=ncol(x))
diag(Rnew) <- paste(diag(R), " ", sep="")
rownames(Rnew) <- colnames(x)
colnames(Rnew) <- paste(colnames(x), "", sep="")

## remove upper triangle of correlation matrix
if(removeTriangle[1]=="upper"){
    Rnew <- as.matrix(Rnew)
    Rnew[upper.tri(Rnew, diag = TRUE)] <- ""
    Rnew <- as.data.frame(Rnew)
}

## remove lower triangle of correlation matrix
else if(removeTriangle[1]=="lower"){
    Rnew <- as.matrix(Rnew)
    Rnew[lower.tri(Rnew, diag = TRUE)] <- ""
    Rnew <- as.data.frame(Rnew)
}

## remove last column and return the correlation matrix
Rnew <- cbind(Rnew[1:length(Rnew)-1])
if (result[1]=="none") return(Rnew)
else{
    if(result[1]=="html") print(xtable(Rnew), type="html")
    else print(xtable(Rnew), type="latex") 
}
```

}

Thank you for your help!