# stargazer: create table with regression output without model objects

Tags: r, stargazer

I have computed several models, using both `glm()` and `rxGlm()` (the second one is from `Microsoft R`). Unfortunately, `rxGlm()` does not store all information required by `stargazer`. So when trying to create the summary table (even after adjusting the `RxGlm` data via `as.glm()` ), I get the following error message:

```
Error in qr.lm(object) : lm object does not have a proper 'qr' component.
 Rank zero or should not have used lm(.., qr=FALSE).
```

I am already reading out separetly the t-statistics and p-values and feed them back to `stargazer` separately. However, stargazer still requires the model output objects to be stored in the workspace and otherwise sends an error message.

This is how I extract the statistics from the model output:

```
obj1.t <- summary(obj1)$coef[ , "z value"]
obj1.p <- summary(obj1)$coef[ , "Pr(>|z|)"]
```

This is a simplified form of my `stargazer` command, where `se =` and `p =` are used to feed back the previously extracted statistics.

```
stargazer(list(obj1, obj2), 
          type = "html", table.layout = "cd=!t-s-!a=!n", star.cutoffs=c(0.05,0.01,0.001), no.space = TRUE, 
          omit = c(1989:2015), font.size = "normalsize", 
          out = "Test.html", 
          df= FALSE, 
          column.labels = c("(1)", "(2)"),
          add.lines = list(c("fixed effects", "No", "Yes")), 
          dep.var.labels = c("Dummy"),
          title = "GLM PROBIT MODEL",
          se= list(obj1.t, obj2.t),
          p = list(obj1.p, obj2.p),
          notes = "t statistics shown in parentheses")
```

Now my question: is there a way to create regression output tables with stargazer without having to provide the model output objects? So basically store all the required data in separate vectors and then feed them back to stargazer? `RxGlm` summaries provide all the information that is necessary to fill the regression results table manually. However, I am looking for a way to do it automatically.

Comment: Please provide [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Minimal working example is difficult in this case because running `RxGlm`models requires a separate version of R that needs to be installed first. I will add an example of my stargazer command though

Comment: What you could do is to set `summary = FALSE`, so `stargazer()` creates arbitrary tables from any matrix or df; or therefore test the `tableHTML` package. With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46835323/6574038) or [this hints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43346168/6574038) you can even produce significance stars.